# Research methods specific to former customers?

Tags: user-research, user-expectation

I have the opportunity to reach out to former customers to understand why they decided to move to a competing product. Are there any specific approaches for this type of customer engagement? Any dos or don'ts I should keep in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Five things spring to mind:

1. Analysing any product usage metrics that you have available. Did they use / not-use the product in certain ways. Did none of the customers who left use feature X, but those who continued did? Did they never get past a setup process? Something else?
2. Arrange & do face-to-face interviews. I find that this is, by far, the most useful kind of feedback. Remember these are ex-customers though and they don't owe you anything, so offer some form of compensation for their time.
3. You have to be very clear and up-front with the customer that you're not contacting them in a sales or marketing capacity. Be very clear that you're not trying to get them to come back, you're trying to understand why they left.
4. If you have the kind of product that means the customer has to opt-out / unsubscribe online, then add an *optional* free-form text box at unsubscribe time and ask them why they're leaving.
5. Remember that a customer leaving doesn't necessarily mean that there was something wrong with the product/service. It might mean that you acquired the wrong sort of customer for the product/service. So the feedback you get can be as much for the sales & acquisition channels as it is for the product/service end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that you can use for a Post mortem program. I am assuming that you are going to reach to a limited number of customers( not thousands atleast):

1. Find their purchase history, and see how frequently they made a purchase. If possible try to find a pattern in their purchase.
2. Check for the client servicing/account management. Talk to the person responsible for servicing.
3. As adrianh has mentioned, please don't be salsey about the call, remember you have made this call to help the customer by discovery of the root cause. Always keep the focus of your customer development program on have some value proposition for your old customers.
4. While the above mentioned gives you an idea of what your own company lacked, it prepares you for the raising other important retention related questions, and generating the trust that someone has been looking at the past issues. Now, look for some attributes of the customers itself. Ask them questions that gives you as information as possible. You can ask questions like: "Have you relocated to another location?", "Was our servicing upto the mark?", "Did you feel unappreciated by our service?", "Was there a better service offered by a competitor?",etc and try to find if the purchasing habits have changed over the time. This will cross-verify information from your workplace, as well as rely on the real attributes.